# Not able to run encoded php file using zend guard

Tags: zend-guard

I want to encode my php files to give this code to the testers to test. For that,I have encoded my php file using zend quard. While taking license it I am getting,below warning,

[image]

I tried to run that encoded file, I get this error.

[image]

How to solve this error and how to run my encode php file.I am using xampp how to configure xampp with zendguard. I am new to zend guard since yesterday I am trying to solve this.But, I did not get any soluctions. Can any one assist me to solve this.